# Problems with connecting to LDAPS

Tags: java, ssl, ldap

While Im connecting to LDAPS I get the following Exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:189)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:121)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:312)
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:350)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:927)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.waitForClose(SSLSocketImpl.java:1723)
    at sun.security.ssl.HandshakeOutStream.flush(HandshakeOutStream.java:122)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.kickstart(Handshaker.java:909)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.kickstartHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1439)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1304)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1355)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1339)
    at InstallCert.main(InstallCert.java:72)
```

I'm connecting using the following code:

```
InputStream in = new FileInputStream(file);
KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
ks.load(in, passphrase);
in.close();

SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TSL");
TrustManagerFactory tmf =
    TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
tmf.init(ks);
X509TrustManager defaultTrustManager = (X509TrustManager)tmf.getTrustManagers()[0];
SavingTrustManager tm = new SavingTrustManager(defaultTrustManager);
context.init(null, new TrustManager[] {tm}, null);
SSLSocketFactory factory = context.getSocketFactory();

System.out.println("Opening connection to " + host + ":" + port + "...");
SSLSocket socket = (SSLSocket)factory.createSocket(host, port);
socket.setSoTimeout(10000);
try {
    System.out.println("Starting SSL handshake...");
    socket.startHandshake();
    socket.close();
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("No errors, certificate is already trusted");
} catch (SSLException e) {
    System.out.println();
    e.printStackTrace(System.out);
}
```

Port is : 636. Domain Controller is on Windows 2012. When I connect to domain controller on Windows 2008 there is no problem, it works correctly.

Does it mean that LDAP doesn't use SSL?

Comment: Have you enabled LDAPs on the DC? AFAIK it is disabled by default.